# Nginx 400 SSL handshaking

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm using nginx and I recently add certificate on a website, and I got strange error.

Here is a part of my access.log :

```
x.y.z.w - - [12/Nov/2014:15:16:09 +0100]  "-" 400 0 "-" "-" Host : -
x.y.z.w - - [12/Nov/2014:15:16:09 +0100]  "-" 400 0 "-" "-" Host : -
```

I see nothing in error.log but when I force error.log to be more precise, I got :

```
2014/11/12 15:16:09 [info] 16027#0: *24870 client closed prematurely connection while SSL handshaking, client: x.y.z.w, server: sub.domain.com
2014/11/12 15:16:09 [info] 16027#0: *24871 client closed prematurely connection while SSL handshaking, client: x.y.z.w, server: sub.domain.com
```

Here is a part of my nginx config file :

```
server
{
        listen 80;

        server_name sub.domain.com;
        root /var/www;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}


server
{
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name sub.domain.com;
        root /var/www;

        ssl_certificate /var/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/server.key;
        ...
```

There is no error on client side.

It is normal ? Where does it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

> It is normal ? Where does it come from ?

It might be from clients which close before finishing the handshake. This might be the case if they get the certificate inside the handshake, fail to verify the certificate because it is self-signed or other reasons, and have to check with the user if they should continue.

Comment: No, if an HTTP 400 error code is logged then it passed the handshake phasis.

Comment: @XavierLucas: Then what code is logged if it received no request because the SSL handshake did not complete? I cannot think of any code other than "400 Bad Request" which would make sense in this case.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. HTTP is network layer 7, SSL/TLS layer 5 & 6. In case handshake doens't complete, it's logged in nginx error log. Access log is for HTTP requests logging.

Comment: In my experience handshake failures do show up in the access log but I don't recall the status code. I think a dummy status code is used, perhaps the 400...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using nginx default access log format, this means the handshake has **completed** but the client didn't send any valid request after that (HTTP `400` code  -> invalid request).

This could for instance be due to some SSL scanner (not really surprising considering the current context).

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not scanner in my case. I test myself and sometime it's happen, but no error in browser, no "error" in server  (error log) but error 400 log in access log (with 200 of course)